# Custom UI - What is more efficient (snappier!!) implementaiton method? UIImageView or Quartz

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

A question on iOS iPad UI. I am exploring the development of an iOS app that uses some custom toolbar shapes and some custom UI elements like the collection pop-up in iBooks etc.

I am wondering what is the best way to implement this so that I am light on resources.

One of the options is to add subviews with a background image and transparent areas to create notches/arrows as seen in the iBooks collection pop-up.

The other option, from WWDC 2011 video "Practical drawing in iOS", where the presenter mention using core-graphics to achieve the same effect using bezier paths etc (i think).

Is one option better/faster/more practical to implement than the other? Creating everything programatically may be faster but it isnt as flexible as, say, drawing something in illustrator. Is this true? or am I completely wrong about this?

I appreciate it is a rather poorly worded question but I can try to calrify if it is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pros for code:

- It'll be faster.
- It's more flexible because you can tweak it slightly and it'll change completely how it's drawn.
- You can easily make it work for different sizes.

Pros for graphics:

- Quicker to implement.

It's all down to what you're doing really. If graphics work for you then use them. If you need the flexibility of doing the drawing in code, then use that. Also you might find that you implement it using graphics to start with and then later down the line switch to drawing in code.

Comment: Two other thoughts: don't optimize too early, and Instruments provides a great basis for determining where your bottlenecks are.